# putting on some soothing sounds. what does this exactly mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

After a stressful day, relaxing in a comfortable chair, **putting on some soothing sounds**, and reading something light and entertaining are all good methods to get ready for some restful sleep.

I thought 'put' is a transitive verb but here we see "on" saw I wonder why there is "on".

Could any one explain? I know the meaning due to context.

Comment: 'playing some recorded music that will be soothing' (presumably from switching  _on_ the radio or putting _on_ a disc, though nowadays it may well be other media).

Answer (score 0):

This idiom might be hard to understand if you've never used a record player before.

*To put something on some other thing* can be used to mean that you physically pick up thing1 and place it on top of thing2. For example, you can put your keys on a table.

The idiom "to put some music on" comes from the time where in order to listen to music, you actually *did* physically put a record on the turntable of the record player. And before that, on the grammophone.

So, we go from

- *to put a record on the record player* to
- *to put a record on* to
- *to put some music on* to
- *to put some (jazz / tunes / sounds / Foo Fighters) on*

You could even hear something like *to put some Miles on*, which would mean that you listen to a recording of Miles Davis.

And even though the days where you physically placed a recording medium onto a player mechanism, the idiom persists to this day, where we typically don't even have physical mediums we store our music on.

Comment: It looked convincing at first glance - but thinking a bit further afield, I simply can't believe the rationale for idiomatic *Every night we put the news on after dinner* is that radios and televisions are a bit like record players. In any case, we also *put the radio on before breakfast*.

Comment: By the time of the very first programmatic radio transmission (i.e. the first one that was not simply a navigation or test signal, or used for communication), the gramophone was twenty years old, the phonograph thirty years old. I can certainly imagine the older technology having influenced language by then.